# When collection->map returnes array then data in Collection raise error

Tags: laravel, collections, resources

In laravel 6 app I have collection defined as :

```
class PermissionCollection extends ResourceCollection
{

    public static $wrap = 'permissions';

    public function toArray($request)
    {

        return $this->collection->transform(function($permission){
            return [
                'id' => $permission->id,
                'name' => $permission->name,
                'is_checked' => !empty($permission->is_checked) ? $permission->is_checked : null,
                'guard_name' => $permission->guard_name,
                'created_at' => $permission->created_at,
            ];
        });
    }

}
```

I use it in a control, like :

```
$permissions = $user->permissions->all();

$userPermissionLabels= Permission
    ::get()
    ->map(function ($item) use($permissions) {
        $is_checked= false;
        foreach( $permissions as $nextPermission ) {
            if($nextPermission->permission_id === $item->id) {
                $is_checked= true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return [ 'id'=> $item->id, 'name'=> $item->name, 'is_checked' => $is_checked];
    })
    ->all();

return (new PermissionCollection($userPermissionLabels));
```

and I got error :

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

Looks like the reason is that collection->map returnes array of data, not objects.
If there is a way to fix it without creating new collection(using array) ?

```
MODIFIED :
```

I logged loging in my collection,

```
public function toArray($request)
{

    return $this->collection->transform(function($permission){

        \Log::info(' PermissionCollection $permission');
        \Log::info($permission);

        return [
            'id' => $permission->id,
            'name' => $permission->name,
            'is_checked' => !empty($permission->is_checked) ? $permission->is_checked : null,
            'guard_name' => $permission->guard_name,
            'created_at' => $permission->created_at,
        ];
    });
}
```

and I see in logs:

```
PermissionCollection $permission  
array (
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'App admin',
  'is_checked' => false,
)  
 local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
The value is valid array, not null.
```

I mean I have already use this collenction in other part of the app, can I use it without creating a new one...

Comment: This has nothing to do with what the map function returns. Is it possible that your permissions collection contains `null` values?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get this error because you CollectionResource need to object of the Permission model, but in your case it is trying to get id from an array, after map function. Try to extend your model instead of returning an new array